# ASP.NET ListView - total value (sum) for a column

Tags: asp.net, listview, user-controls

I'm writing a reusable control - lets call it MyListView - inherited from standard ASP.NET ListView control. It's datasource is always set to a LinqDataSource and I need to calculate total value for a specific column (sum of all values for that column). Which way is the best  to calculate a total value? I was thinking of OnItemDataBound event and computing total there using global variable, but I also need paging in MyListView (using standard Pager control) and this event is fired only for rows on currently visible page, not for all rows in the datasource. I also don't want to calculate total sum in code behind of ASPX page, I want to just specify a column name in aspx, and MyListView will automatically compute total value for the column.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you're using pagination it's not easy to have that result. I think you should consider to put the row used for totals *outside* the ListView (so you can use LINQ to compute totals too, I guess you don't want to enumerate all items to compute a total when it can be done quickly on SQL side).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim total As Integer
For Each Items As ListViewItem In lV_allItems.Items
    Dim lbl As Label = CType(Items.FindControl("Quantitytxtbox"), Label)
    total += lbl.Text
Next
Label1.Text = "TOTAL FRAME ADDED : " + total.ToString
```

I put this code in the page prerender and it works just fine, you have to make sure what is in the columns is an integer otherwise you need to convert.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get total value from database my suggession is to pass an output parameter with you query / linkq to the database and get the sum of all records from database in the same call in which you get data.

Answer (score 0):

assume you use this query to bind you listview

```
var queryforBind= (from c in table).Skip(1).Take(10); //1 and 10 can be changed according to your requirement
```

and after bind your list view call this query to compute total.

```
var sum = queryforBind.Sum(x => x => x.Field); //Field can be according your requirement
```